# Comma in «самый что ни на есть»

Tags: пунктуация

Do I need a comma in such phrases as:

> Да он самый, что ни на есть преступник.
>
> Математика — самая, что ни на есть точная наука.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you don't.

Rosenthal, Справочник по пунктуации, § 41. Цельные по смыслу выражения.

> Запятыми не выделяются сочетания *кто ни на есть, что ни на
>   есть, какой ни на есть* и т. п.:
>
> - Вы охотно допустите, чтоб кто ни на есть… собственноручно в вашей физиономии симметрию исправил. *(С.-Щ.)*
> - Это была самая что ни на есть обыкновенная женщина. *(Эр.)*
> - ...Я лучше погляжу, как вы работаете, — всё какой ни на есть опыт перейму. *(Е.М.)*

Note that in your first sentence, the first comma may (or may not) be redundant as well, depending on the meaning of *да*:

> - Да, он самый что ни на есть преступник // Yes, he's as criminal as they come.
> - Да он самый что ни на есть преступник. // But he's as criminal as they come.

Comment: I see. Thank you.